# Can I get a int from my EAX/RAX to a register of the FPU like st0?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, fpu

I am currently working on a small Assembler project in University. Now my question is, is it possible to get a skalar for a multiplication (int), which is given by the user, from my EAX/RAX Register to one of my FPU register like st0? I am using NASM Syntax.

Thank you

Comment: yes. With old x87 code `push rax` `fild qword [rsp]` `add rsp,8`, but if the CPU does support 64b, it must (?) have also some kind of SSE, so using x87 is weird... why?

Comment: What you mean by SEE? :D

Comment: @J.B. SSE is the newer floating point unit available since the Pentium III.  It's what you normally use in 64 bit code.

Comment: wiki about SSE and similar extensions of CPUs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions

Comment: Use SSE2 `cvtsi2sd xmm0, rax` and forget about x87 unless you need 80-bit FP (64-bit mantissa).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to directly transfer the content of an integer register to an x87 floating point register, you have to go through the memory.  Typical code looks like this:

```
PUSH RAX         ; push RAX on the stack
FILD QWORD [RSP] ; load eight byte integer onto FP stack
ADD RSP,8        ; release storage from stack
```

You can usually avoid having to fiddle around with the stack pointer by allocating some storage for this sort of transfer in your stack frame at the beginning of your function.

Comment: If I have a 64 Bit double on the main Stack and i want to get this value to st0, is it allowed to pop the 64 Bit value in RAX to get it via this method in st0? Or is there another "direct" way?

Comment: Or can i just use pop st0 for example?

Comment: @J.B. Well, the first step in my answer is to store the value from `rax` on the stack, so I am not sure what you try to achieve by moving a value from the stack to `rax` and then presumably back to the stack.  You can just do `fld qword [rsp]` to load the double at `[rsp]` onto the x87 stack.  Please refer to the Intel manuals for a comprehensive list of available instruction.

Comment: @J.B. There is no such instruction; `pop` only exists as `pop r64`, `pop r16`, `pop segr`, and `pop r/m64`.    Before asking if you can do something, try and check the manual if the instruction you ask about exists.  Stack Overflow is really not a replacement for you reading the manual.

Comment: @J.B. if you have value already in memory (like in stack), you can do `fld` for float/double values and `fild` for integer values to load them into `st0`. That doesn't modify memory content or `rsp`, so that's why this short example code does `add rsp,8` at end, when the value is already in `st0`, to free the value from the stack (like `pop`).

Comment: @fuz I am sorry, but this is very new to me and everywhere is something else written and thats mind blowing ^^

Comment: One last question: I have a memory Adress in st0 and i want to get the value at this adress to one of the other registers of the FPU, is there a posibillity to do that?

Comment: @J.B. you have memory address in `st0`?? Why? That doesn't make sense. To copy value from one FP register (`stX`) into new `st0` you can du `fld stX` (like `fld st0` will duplicate the value on top of the FP "stack" (make sure you understand the difference between the x86 CPU stack = memory around `rsp` versus x87 register stack = `st0 .. st7` values, they are two different "stacks"). I did recently some DOS 16b programming with x87, and I used this tutorial to refresh my x87 knowledge: http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/index.html (in MASM syntax, so fix it like in this answer)

Comment: @J.B. maybe the best thing would be to post new question, with some example of how you would write some code to achieve basic tasks, like load double value from memory, or add two values, etc... and how do you understand that code, and how it does not work as expected when you debug it, or when you compare it with particular book/tutorial/docs, so we can see which parts you are misunderstanding, or maybe you have wrong tutorials, etc.. Maybe search for some working examples and check them in debugger too. And using x87 instruction in x86_64 is questionable (unless you need 80 bit precision).

Comment: @Ped7g thank you so much so far So i try to explain what i generally want to do. I have a value in the memory (type: double) and i want to multiply it with a factor X (also a double). The address of this value is on the stack, like the faktor i want to multiply with. I have the understanding that every floatingpoint operation has to be done by the FPU. So i thought i have to get X and the value at the address in the FPU. My main problem at the moment is i am not sure how i get the value at the address into the FPU. Is it allowed to cache the value in for example RAX? Like:
mov RAX,[addr]

Comment: and then i move the value with the code above in the FPU, multiply it with X and get it back in RAX to move the new value back to the adress in the memory?

Comment: @J.B. Addresses are integers, as a rule of thumb, you want to keep them in general purpose registers like `rax`, `rbx`, etc.  Suppose the address of the datum you want to load is in `rax`, you just write `fld qword [rax]` to load a double from that address. It is probably a good idea to get familiar with the fundamentals of x86 assembly before starting to program the x87 FPU.

Answer (score 3):

Example (for 64b linux and NASM) for your calculation in the comments under fuz's answer:

```
; file: x87test.asm
section .data
    some_value  dq 1234.5678    ; double value

section .bss
    result      resq    1       ; reserve memory for result double
    result2     resq    1       ; reserve memory for second result (code variant 2)

section .text
    global _start
    _start:
        ; initializations of example
        finit                       ; initialize FPU
        ; store "factor" into the stack
        mov     rax,__float64__(51.6)
        push    rax
        ; "value" is already in memory at address `some_value`

        ; load the FPU-stack with factor and value
        fld     qword [some_value]  ; st0 = value
        fld     qword [rsp]         ; st0 = factor, st1 = value
        add     rsp, 8              ; release the CPU stack space occupied by factor (by "push rax")

        ; Do the calculation with st0 and st1
        fmulp   st1                 ; st0 = st0 * st1 with "pop" (the FP stack holds only "st0")
            ; "fmul" without "p" would keep the "st1" intact (value) and st0 = product
        fstp    qword [result]      ; "pop" st0 into memory at "result" address

        ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ; other variant, skipping the load of second value, as the FMUL can use memory argument too
        ; store "factor" into the stack
        mov     rax,__float64__(7.89)
        push    rax

        ; load the FPU-stack with value
        fld     qword [some_value]  ; st0 = value
        fmul    qword [rsp]         ; st0 = value * factor
        add     rsp, 8              ; release the CPU stack space occupied by factor (by "push rax")
        fstp    qword [result2]     ; "pop" st0 into memory at "result2" address

        ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ; exit back to linux
        mov     eax, 60
        xor     edi, edi
        syscall
```

Build and execute with:

```
nasm -f elf64 x87test.asm -l x87test.lst -w+all
ld -b elf64-x86-64 -o x87test x87test.o
./x87test
```

No input/output should happen, just clean exit. Check with debugger, single stepping over each instruction, and watching the stack (pointed at by `rsp`) memory area, and x87 FPU "stack" (`st0 .. st7` values), and memory at `result` address.

---

edit:

> I have the understanding that every floatingpoint operation has to be done by the FPU.

Absolutely no, if you think so, you are still missing the whole principle of computers. Everything in computer is encoded as sequence of bits (value 0 or 1). So your statement when translated to this basic premise is "I have one bit pattern here, other bit pattern there, a well defined operation describing which third bit pattern some operation should produce, but I can't do it if I don't have FPU" - does it sounds logical to you?

It's lot of work (tens of x86 instructions) to multiply two IEEE-754 "double" values manually, you need to extract the exponent and mantissa parts of those values, multiply mantissas and exponents separately, and then normalize/clamp the value and compose a valid IEEE-754 "double" type result back into 64 bits, but it's definitely doable without FPU, that's what the software emulation of x87 did all the time before 80486DX and Pentium CPUs made hardware FPU common (80486SX and the predecessors 80286 and 80386 didn't have x87 built-in, it was sold as separate expensive coprocessor chip). In times of 386 most of the people did use SW emulators of x87 to run the specialized software which required FPU.

The thing is, that if you understand how something (input information) is encoded in bits, and what you want as output information (encoded in bits), and you can describe some algorithm of bit-manipulation operations converting the input value into output value, then you can implement such algorithm by any Turing-compliant CPU (although with some very limited systems like 8 bit CPUs it may be major PITA to create IEEE-754 double*double calculation, as it will take probably hundreds of instructions, or you may even run out of resources, if the memory is too limited to hold so many bits at the same time).

The x87 FPU is just hardware accelerated solution for floating point operations, it's not the only possible way how to calculate something.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful ;)  My statement was a little bit wrong. I just wanted to say that there is no other simple way to multiply two floating-point numbers

Comment: @J.B. Well, you could use the SSE floating point unit.  It's slightly simpler to use.

Comment: @J.B. plus it also depends what you mean by "floating-point" number, if you mean IEEE-754 encoding, then yes, the x87 and SSE are simplest way on x86-64. But you can encode floating point values differently, for example in "fixed-point" way, or as separate digits with some custom packing scheme (often used by something like "decimal" type in SQL or arbitrary precision math libraries), then the code may be simpler without x87 or SSE, for example the "fixed point" way is designed especially for CPUs without HW FPU, or when you need specific range of values only with fixed granularity.